# Why are there so many instances of Python on my system? Which one of these is my system actually using?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm using a Mac and this is a screenshot of the files in my `/usr/local/bin`[image: Working directory is /usr/local/bin]

This is a screenshot of the files in `/opt/homebrew/opt`[image: Working directory here is /opt/homebrew/opt]

I'm wondering why I have this amount of Pythons on my Mac. I feel like it's cluttered and confusing. I am also aware that the Macs have a built in Python so just to be clear, I'm not trying to get rid of that. What makes this confusing is that I don't know which Python is in use to update. Typing `python3 --version` returns 3.9.5 when the latest is 3.9.7. Furthermore, I thought that I had updated my Python through the official website, but found out that I just updated the IDLE that downloads when you install Python from Python.org.

Although a seemingly trivial question, any feedback and knowledge would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `which python` at the terminal will tell you the path of the command `python`. It might be a symlink so use `ls -l` on that path to check.

Comment: I see. `which Python3` points to `/opt/homebrew/bin/Python3`. In this directory, there are files such as `idle3` `idle3.9` `pydoc3` `pydoc3.9` `python3` `python3.9` `python3-config` `python3.9-config`. Is there a reason why there seems to be a pattern with the 3 and 3.9 versions. Is one of each of these obsolete?

Comment: `python3` and `python3.9` should be the same thing, I'm guessing at least 2 of these 3 are symlinks. pydoc, idle, and config are different commands with different purposes, not simply 'python'.

Comment: Interesting. I appreciate your insight, I'm just going to leave things as they are so I don't mess anything up. I do dislike the clutter but thank you!

Comment: That's for the best. Most of this isn't clutter at all, the aliases for `python` can be quite useful.